# Upload multiple files in CodeIgniter not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

in my CodeIgniter project I'm uploading files during the project creation. Here's the uploading function:

```
public function addProcess()
{
echo 'test';
    if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('album', 'Album', 'trim|required|callback_check_select', 'xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $data['albums'] = $this->album_model->albumList();
            $this->adminTheme('admin/addSong',$data);
        }
        else
        { 
                $error = 0;
                $this->load->library('upload');  
                $total_count_of_files = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

                $album = $this->input->post('album');
                $songs = $this->input->post('song');
                $artist = $this->input->post('artist');


                for($i=0; $i< $total_count_of_files; $i++)
                {

                    if(!$songs[$i])
                        $songs[$i] = "Track-".($i+1);
                    if(!$artist[$i])
                        $artist[$i] = " ";

                 $_FILES['file']['name']    = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
                 $_FILES['file']['type']    = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
                 $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                 $_FILES['file']['error']       = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
                 $_FILES['file']['size']    = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

                 $config['upload_path']   = './upload/';
                 $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp3';
                 $config['max_size']      = '0';
                 $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
                 $config['encrypt_name']    =   TRUE;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                        if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
                        {
                            $msg = $this->upload->data();
                            $name = $msg['file_name'];

                            $error += 0;
                            $this->song_model->add($songs[$i], $artist[$i], $name, $album);

                        }else{
                            $errorStr[] = "$songs[$i] Upload Faild";
                            $error += 1;
                        }
                }


            //$this->album_model->add();
            if($error == 0)
            {
                //$this->msg('admin/song','Successfully added..Redirecting now...');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->msg('admin/song','Successfully added..Redirecting now...');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('admin/album');
    }
}
```

another function for doupload

```
   public function do_upload()
    {
        $upload_path_url = base_url().'uploads/';

        $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp3';
        $config['max_size'] = '30000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload', $error);

        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
        $info->name = $data['file_name'];
            $info->size = $data['file_size'];
        $info->type = $data['file_type'];
            $info->url = $upload_path_url .$data['file_name'];

        $info->thumbnail_url = $upload_path_url .$data['file_name'];
            $info->delete_url = base_url().'upload/deleteImage/'.$data['file_name'];
            $info->delete_type = 'DELETE';


        if (IS_AJAX) {
            echo json_encode(array($info));

        } else {
            $file_data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
            $this->load->view('admin/upload_success', $file_data);
        }
    }
}
```

my form code

```
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Song Name - Add New</h2>
      <div class="error">
        <?php   echo validation_errors(); ?>
      </div>
      <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'myform');  ?>
      <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/song/addProcess',$attributes); ?>
        <div class="line">
          <label style="width: 160px;">Album:</label>
          <select class="category" name="album" style="width: 280px;">
            <option value="select">Select Album</option>
              <?php foreach($albums as $album): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $album['id']; ?>">

                    <?php echo $album['root_name']." --> ".$album['category_name']." --> ".$album['album_name']; ?></option>
              <?php endforeach ?>
          </select>

                    <input class="form-submit" style="margin-top: 6px;" type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
        </div>
        <!--end line-->





                <div id="nameFields">
                    <div class="line">
                        <input type="text" name="song[]" class="input1" style="width: 180px;" placeholder="Song Name" />
                        <input type="text" name="artist[]" class="input1" style="width: 180px;" placeholder="Artist Name" />
                        <input type="file" name="userfile[]" class="category" style="width:80px;" />
                    </div>
            <!--end line-->
                </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="form-submit" style="margin-right: 180px;" />

      </form>
    </div>
    <!--end container--> 



<script type="text/javascript">
                    function add_fields() {
                                document.getElementById('nameFields').innerHTML += "<div class='line'><input type='text' name='song[]' class='input1' style='width: 180px;' placeholder='Song Name' /><input type='text' name='artist[]' class='input1' style='width: 180px;' placeholder='Artist Name' /><input type='file' name='userfile[]' class='category' style='width:80px;' /></div>";
                        }


</script>
```

However this does not do anything. The files are not being uploaded. Even an empty directory is not being created. Could anybody help me to find the error?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your form code?

Comment: form code added @kumar_v

Answer (score 0):

In your addProcess code, remove below code

```
$_FILES['file']['name']    = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
$_FILES['file']['type']    = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
$_FILES['file']['error']       = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
$_FILES['file']['size']    = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
```

and try

```
foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $fileObject) 
{
    if (!empty($fileObject['name']))
    {
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fieldname))
        {
            $errors[] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        }
        else
        {
             //success code
        }
    }
}
```